# Formose reaction - mechanism of first step

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

The following image was taken from wikkipedia's article about the [Formose reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formose_reaction). What is the mechanism of the first step of the reaction sequence? How do the two formaldehyde molecules condense?

[image]

Comment: Wikipedia says: 'The reaction is catalyzed by a base and a divalent metal such as calcium.' So I'd guess first complexation, the proton abstraction, then C-C bond formation.

Comment: Would it help to know that 1. under standard conditions, formaldehyde is a gas, 2. the reaction is performed in aqueous solution, 3. in aqueous solution, formaldehyde mostly exists as a hydrate $\ce{H2C(OH)2}$?

Comment: There are many articles on the topic. I am far too lazy to read them and write up an answer but here are some: [*Tetrahedron Lett.*, **1959**, *1* (21), 22-26](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403901994870), [*J. Org. Chem.*, **2006**, *71* (25), 9503–9505](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo061770h), [*J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **2014**, *136* (10), 3720–3723](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja410886c)

Comment: @orthocresol In none of these articles is the first reaction considered.

Comment: @Klaus I don't understand. There must be some deprotonation step but it seems so improbable in any case.

Comment: It is. There are two pathways for the first reaction - one occurs without catalysis and the mechanism seems to be unknown (the last reference writes that it may involve radiation), and the other is catalysed ostensibly by the products **2**, **3** and **4**. Most of the discussion is focused on the catalysed reaction.

Comment: So there isn't a definite answer about the mechanism?

Comment: @Marko I find your question very interesting! I think that we can definitely rule out direct deprotonation of formaldehyde in aqueous alkaline medium. However, deprotonation of methanediol, formadehyde exists as a hydrate in  aqueous solution, seems possible, and it might be further facilitated by the presence of larger cations. But till now, I haven't figured out how an *umpolung*, rather than a *Cannizzaro* reaction might take place under these conditions.

Comment: Only a radical mechanism seems plausible: homolytical cleavage of C=O bond, addition of the radical to the other formaldehyde molecules and hydrogen abstraction by O*. That would fit early Earth's conditions, but I don't know whether this reaction works in the lab and how, so I can't be sure.